# Play/Scala: use orElse to compose with ActionBuilder?

Tags: scala, playframework, pac4j

We use play-pac4j for our authentication in our play application.

We would like to have the same route/controller endpoint but with a different behaviour dependending on the user Role.

Conceptually, this would do something like:

```
 val ACTION_ONE: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent] = Secure(
    JWT_CLIENT,  Authorizers.Role1
 )(anyContentLarge)

 val ACTION_TWO: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent] = Secure(
    JWT_CLIENT,  Authorizers.Role2
 )(anyContentLarge)

 def index = ACTION_ONE.async{ req => index1(req) } orElse ACTION_TWO.async{ req => index2(req) }

 def index1(req: Request[AnyContent]) = //... behavior with role1

 def index2(req: Request[AnyContent]) = //... behavior with role2
```

But the composition of Play `Actions` provides only `andThen`, no `orElse`.
Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I implemented it :)

It uses 'fallBackToNext', a method we already have in our codebase that behave as fallBackTo but with an async lambda parameter, so the next future is executed only if the first one is already a failure (preventing big computations from happening when not needed, but reducing parallelism).

Here are most of the logic:

```
/**
 * This combination of action is the implementation class of the "orElse" operator,
 * allowing to have one and only one action to be executed within the given actions
 */
class EitherActions[A](actions: Seq[Action[A]]) extends Action[A] {

  require(actions.nonEmpty, "The actions to combine should not be empty")

  override def parser: BodyParser[A] = actions.head.parser
  override def executionContext: ExecutionContext = actions.head.executionContext

  /**
   * @param request
   * @return either the first result to be successful, or the first to be failure
   */
  override def apply(
      request: Request[A]
  ): Future[Result] = {

    // as we know actions is nonEmpty, we can start with actions.head and directly fold on actions.tail
    // this removes the need to manage an awkward "zero" value in the fold
    val firstResult = actions.head.apply(request)

    // we wrap all apply() calls into changeUnauthorizedIntoFailure to be able to use fallbackToNext on 403
    val finalResult = actions.tail.foldLeft( changeUnauthorizedIntoFailure(firstResult) ) {
      ( previousResult, nextAction ) =>

        RichFuture(previousResult).fallbackToNext{ () =>
          changeUnauthorizedIntoFailure(nextAction.apply(request))
        }(executionContext)
    }

    // restore the original message
    changeUnauthorizedIntoSuccess(finalResult)
  }


  /**
   * to use fallBackToNext, we need to have failed Future, thus we change the Success(403) into a Failure(403)
   * we keep the original result to be able to restore it at the end if none of the combined actions did success
   */
  private def changeUnauthorizedIntoFailure(
      before: Future[Result]
  ): Future[Result] = {
    val after = before.transform {
      case Success(originalResult) if originalResult.header.status == Unauthorized =>
        Failure(EitherActions.UnauthorizedWrappedException(originalResult = originalResult))
      case Success(originalResult) if originalResult.header.status == Forbidden =>
        Failure(EitherActions.UnauthorizedWrappedException(originalResult = originalResult))
      case keepResult@_ => keepResult
    }(executionContext)
    after
  }

  /**
   * after the last call, if we still have a UnauthorizedWrappedException, we change it back to a Success(403)
   * to restore the original message
   */
  private def changeUnauthorizedIntoSuccess(
      before: Future[Result]
  ): Future[Result] = {
    val after = before.transform {
      case Failure(EitherActions.UnauthorizedWrappedException(_, _, result)) => Success(result)
      case keepResult@_ => keepResult
    }(executionContext)
    after
  }

  def orElse( other: Action[A]): EitherActions[A] = {
    new EitherActions[A]( actions :+ other)
  }

}

object EitherActions {

  private case class UnauthorizedWrappedException(
      private val message: String = "",
      private val cause: Throwable = None.orNull,
      val originalResult: Result,
  ) extends Exception(message, cause)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to compose in a `orElse` manner the `Action`s.

However you should be able to create a "combined" `ActionBuilder` that uses your 2 existing `ActionBuilder`s and do the `orElse` logic. Though you would only be able to provide one body to run. And this body would have to rely on something like the `AuthenticatedRequest#profiles` to determine what to do.

Something like:

```scala
def index = ACTION_COMBINED.async{ req: AuthenticatedRequest =>
  // Check something on req.profiles
  if (...) index1(req) else index2(req)
}
```

*I'm not familiar with play-pac4j to be more precise*

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is that a unauthorized Secure() Action from pac4j will not continue to the next combined one....